# using static property to bind to Value in animation

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm curious as to why this does not work:

```
<EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="{x:Static wpfApplication10:HelperThingy.X}"  />
```

I get an error saying '1' is not a valid value for property 'Value'.

I'm trying to work around not being able to bind to a value in animation defined in a style.

Comment: What datatype is `X`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure X is a `double` and not a `string` or `integer`.

The Value property is a `double` and assigning a string or integer to it will not automatically convert the string/integer to a double.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Evgeniy - I beg to differ: I think that X is an int or a string and that causes the error message. That is why it doesn't work. That is why I consider this an answer.

Comment: @user1604008 - just to make this a bit more valuable for others: What was wrong?

Comment: Ah so your going to make me admit are you.... OK, fine, it was an integer. mea culpa